# How to iterate over the elements of array of arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have a square of fixed size represented as n arrays each with n elements. I want to write a function checking if it's a [magic square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square). The first thing to check is if all inner arrays have the same sum. However, how do I iterate over the first elements of each inner array, then over the second elements up to the last elements?

Comment: Nest iterators, outer then inner, check sums.

Comment: That's even better, although I was thinking the operations could be combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) is your friend.